# How to round off image in PHP with transparency?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a scenario where I have square images e.g. 500x500

I need to generate a rounded corner image with transparent borders. I am able to achieve this using Image Moo library (in CodeIgniter framework) however the library adds white color instead of making the border part transparent.

I checked another piece of code and it's doing same, by filling the border part with white color in order to round off corners.

Is there any way I can round off corners while maintaining transparency of borders?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have only been able to do it for PNGs using `imagealphablending($targetImg, false)` and `imagesavealpha($targetImg, true);` but I have failed to do it with GIFs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS-Tag `border-radius`.

For example:

```
img {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Check out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgL8oyat/)